# Google InfoWindow Displaying Vertical Scrollbar When Not Needed

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, infowindow

I'm trying to put the finishing touches on a new address search page for a local school district, but can't figure out why a vertical scrollbar keeps showing up in popup window (via Google Map API) when it is not needed.  The vertical scrollbar always seems to show up on Chrome, Firefox and Safari; however it seems to work better in IE.  It also seems to work well on my iPad.  The site uses SharePoint 2010 and I have to tell you it is not easy to work with in my opinion.  Anyway, if you click on the map on any of the colored regions or icons, you get a popup window describing the location.  The problem is the vertical scrollbar keeps showing up when it is not needed.  Does anyone know how to get rid of the vertical scrollbar in Google Maps API?

Site:  http://www.paplv.org/SitePages/Address-Search.aspx

Any help is appreciated,

Scott

Answer (score 0):

I can't seem to replicate the problem on the page you linked (probably fixed by now), though it is a common issue with the latest Google Maps API.

I've had success with applying the style "line-height: normal ! important" to the map's <div>.

Answer (score 0):

You've probably figured this out by now, but in case someone else has the same issue...
I created a div block inside the addListener function to correct the scrolling issue.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) { 
  var myString = '<div id="infoWindow" style="white-space: nowrap;">'
  + '<div id="bodyContent">'
  + markers[i][2] + markers[i][3]
  + '</div>'
  + '</div>';
}
return function() {
infowindow.setContent(myString); 
infowindow.open(map, marker);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem also and just solved it myself.

It's to do with the font included automatically.

```
.gm-style {
    font-family: Roboto,Arial,sans-serif;
}
```

When creating your infowindow html content wrap it in a div and add a class:

```
// infowindow html
html = "<div class='infowindowStyle'><p><span class='title'>" + name + "</span><br />" + address + "</p></div>";
```

Then add a class to your styles:

```
.infowindowStyle { font-family:Verdana; }
```

This should fix the issue for you.